# Dynamically Centering a Div

Tags: css, layout, html, dynamic

I went to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Google Coding](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html), and they both give the same example. They say you can center a div like this, but it doesn't work. Anybody knows why? I also would like to know the best way to center a div. I tried to do `margin: 0 auto`; it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div must be given an defined width in order for the margin trick to work: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLxy/)

```
<div style='width:800px;margin:0 auto;'>Div Middle</div>
```

Comment: Huh? It's only because if width is 100% then auto would calculate to 0 since there is no surrounding space to marginize. This trick also works with percentages, I use it with 75% width all the time.

Comment: By absolute width, I meant a defined width =p

Answer (score 2):

What browser are you using? Do you have any example code. Perhaps a gist.github.com or jsfiddle.net.

If I infer what you want you need a few things.

1. A containing DIV
2. CSS `width` defined for child DIV
3. CSS `margin: 0 auto;` for child DIV

The following example code is from: http://jsfiddle.net/sukima/5RQpw

### HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <!-- Must have a container div -->
    <div id="child">
        This is a test
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#parent {
    background-color: green;
    /* Center's text not div. Can be here or in child. */
    /* text-align: center; */
}
#child {
    background-color: red;
    width: 80px; /* Required. Develop your own calculation. */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centers the div */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see everyone basically posting the same thing, but they are all making up rules that it must be within a containing division (fyi, `<body>` works perfectly fine as a 'container', it doesn't *have* to be a division) or must have a set width. Obviously, if you don't set a width, then the margin will have no effect because it will expand to the full width (thus no margin area).

Without you posting the actual HTML and CSS that you're using, we really can't help you at all, because we have no idea what's going on. By standards, `margin: 0 auto` should work, period. Like stated above, even if you don't specify the width, the 'auto' is still applied and is merely calculated as 0 as the division expands to the entire width and thus there is no margin to fill.

The only thing that comes to mind is that you are removing the block-level styling. Perhaps you are defining it as `display: inline`? Inline elements cannot have margins and would pay attention to the text-align property of the parent element instead. Also, if you are floating the division in any way, you obviously can't then say center it, because the point of floating is to push it to the left or right (not the center). We could continue to speculate, but really you should improve your question. Another note to add: *you cannot use `margin: 0 auto` with fixed position elements*.

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 0; /* reset */
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
text-align: center; /* For IE */
```

You neet to `text-align: left` for the inner parts after.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what size your box will be, you can use [shrink wrapping techniques](http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Shrink-Wrap) to allow you to still use `margin:0 auto`. (In the tutorial I linked to, they show just this very thing done with both `display:inline` and `display:table`.)

**Edit:** My bad. They only used `margin:0 auto` in their demonstration of `display:table` shrink wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
#content
{    
    width: 740px;
    clear: both; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You require IE8 and above (I tried this on 9). IE complains about running active x controls before allowing you to run the web page.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #oDiv
      {
        background-color: #CFCFCF;
        position: absolute;
        left:expression(document.body.clientWidth/2-oDiv.offsetWidth/2);
        top:expression(document.body.clientHeight/2-oDiv.offsetHeight/2);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="oDiv">Example DIV</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem, of course, is that this is not compatible with all browsers. Centering a div vertically and horizontally strictly using CSS is more complicated but can be done. (It helps to use `&nbsp;` in the right places).

Comment: "This is not compatible with all browsers." So this *only* works for IE8+? Why on Earth would you *ever* use this then?

Comment: @animuson Thats the point. The title of this question is _dynamically centering a div_. The person who asked the question posted links to msdn resources that refer to dynamic properties. I figured maybe he had a hard time setting up the examples from MS. So far no one has posted the correct answer any way. The person who asked the question probably wants to ask how to both vertically and horizontally align a div within another blocked element.

Comment: They also linked to Google Coding and the `margin: 0 auto` would imply that he was centering it horizontally, since vertically is never mentioned anywhere in the OP.